# Xamarin.Forms ListView Data Binding not working properly in android

Tags: c#, android, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have an application in Xamarin.Forms which has a listview.
When adding items to a list , only one of the parameters seems to be actually going to the view.

XAML:

```xml
<ListView CachingStrategy="RecycleElement"
        HasUnevenRows="True"
        x:Name="listView"
        Grid.Row="1"
        Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
        BackgroundColor="White"
        SeparatorColor="Gray">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <ViewCell>
            <Grid ColumnSpacing="15">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="80"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Margin="10,0,0,0" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding DisplayName}" x:Name="artigoLabel" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"/>
                <Label Grid.Column="1"  HorizontalTextAlignment="End" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Medium" Text="{Binding DisplayQuantity}" x:Name="qtdLabel" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                <Button Grid.Column="2" FontSize="Medium" Image="garbage.png" x:Name="BLabel" HorizontalOptions="End" BackgroundColor="Transparent" Clicked="RemoveRow" WidthRequest="40" CommandParameter="{Binding DisplayName}"/>
            </Grid>
        </ViewCell>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

C#:

```cs
public ObservableCollection<product> myList= newObservableCollection<product>();
product.DisplayName = "some text";
product.DisplayQuantity= "5"; 
myList.Add(product);
listView.ItemsSource = myList;
listView.HeightRequest = (50 * myList.Count);
```

C# (product Entity)

```cs
public class product: ViewCell
{
    public string DisplayName{ get; set; }
    public string DisplayQuantity{ get; set; }

}
```

After running this, only the DisplayName("some text") parameter appears in the ListView.

Something I've noticed also, after attributing the values to the product variable, if I expand the variable properties(in debug), only the DisplayName property is visible.

[image: Only one property is set]

Note: this only happens in Android, in iOS it works fine.

Comment: product class definitely shouldn't inherit from ViewCell, whether it will resolve the problem I don't know but worth to try. Second thing is to check the row height, maybe it simply doesn't fit in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for the help but it didn't work unfortunately :(

Comment: The code you provided works well for me, both of "some text" and "5" are appears in the ListView, please make sure the code can produce the problem which you want.